# Ampersand '&' adds unnecessary characters

Tags: c

I am trying to send character for client socket to server socket. When I get characters in server side i get some additional characters and symbols. can any one suggest me whats going wrong. Before sending i have printed the character it is ok by using following code.

```
r_sendto(int sockfd, char buf, size_t len, int flags,
    const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen) {
printf("\nMessage rec: %c", buf); //Message rec: h  
printf("Message rec: %s", &buf);  // Message rec: h�o�
int sendto_ret_val = sendto(sockfd, &buf, len, flags, dest_addr, addrlen);}
```

When I use the ampersand "&" why does it add additional symbols. I have to send character using "&" and in receiving side I get with additional symbols which is giving me trouble. Can any one clear me hidden logic in &. Thanks in advance.

In receiving section I have following code:

```
char buffer[BUFSIZE];
r_recvfrom(socket_list[socket_index].sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &(socket_list[socket_index].brp_useraddr), &clntAddrLen);
puts(buffer); // it prints  h�w�
```

I am confused, how to remove such unwanted symbols and character in receiving side.

Comment: `%s` expects a null terminated *string*. But `&buf` doesn't point to C-string since `buf` is just a plain char. What you do is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Read about [null terminated strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019615/strings-and-character-with-printf

Answer (score 2):

`s` conversion specifier requires a pointer to a string, but `&buf` is a pointer to a character. By definition a string is *a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character*.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is the "address of" operator in C. When printing a string it MUST be null terminated otherwise you run into memory not allocated to that string (which is usually just garbage) and it can produce undefined behaviour. If you simply need to send one character create an array of size two where the character you need to send is at location 0 and the null character is at position 1.