# Using %s with array

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define SIZE 30

    int main()
    {
        int n; // jumlah data siswa
        int NIS[ SIZE ];
        char nama[ SIZE ];
        int nilai[ SIZE ];
        size_t i;
        int minimum;
        int maximum;
        int total = 0;
        float mean;
        unsigned int pass;
        unsigned int hold;

        printf( "Masukkan banyak data (tidak lebih dari 30) = " );
        scanf( "%d", &n );

        for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
            printf( "NIS: " );
            scanf( "%d", &NIS[ i ]);
            printf("Nama: ");
            scanf( "%s", &nama[ i ]);
            printf( "Nilai: ");
            scanf( "%d", &nilai[ i ]);
            total += nilai[ i ];
            puts( "" );
        }
        system("cls");
        printf("NIS.\t Nama Siswa\t Nilai\n");
        printf("=================================\n");
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                printf("%d\t  %s\t\t   %d\n", NIS[ i ], nama[ i ], nilai[ i ]);
                printf("=================================\n");
            }

        return 0;
    }
```

when i compile line 36, i got warning:

```
D:\Works\ABKC1406\Hasil_Tes_Formatif\main.c|36|warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat]|
```

Comment: the rest program after line 36 is doing fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strings and character with printf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019615/strings-and-character-with-printf)

Comment: try this `printf("%d\t  %s\t\t   %d\n", NIS[ i ], nama, nilai[ i ]);`

Comment: But i want to use string, not a single character by using %c. How do i solve this? @BatCoder

Comment: That solve the warning. But the output is the first character that I input then another string from next input @Nishant

Comment: If you want an array of "string"s you in fact need a 2D-array of characters. What you have (`char nama[ SIZE ];`) is a 1D-array of characters.

Comment: `&nama[ i ]` -> `nama[ i ]`. Voting to close this as simple typo.

Comment: could you shwo me an example? @alk

Comment: I already did that @Lundin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C a "string" is nothing else but an array of `char`. It is terminated (see below "*Note*" for details).

Your code defines exactly one such array:

```
char nama[ SIZE ];
```

So the code defines one "string".

You obviously want an array of strings, so you need to do two things:

- Define a maximum length of any string.
- The number of strings you want.

The latter would be `SIZE`, the former we could define as

```
#define NAMALEN_MAX (100)
```

The definition of the array of "string"s holding all names the user inputs then new would look like this:

```
char nama[SIZE][NAMALEN_MAX];
```

The statement to scan a name would new look like this:

```
scanf("%s", nama[i]);
```

Those are the essential changes correcting your code.

---

Still the code is not save.

Also apply the following two changes though:

1. To not scan in more than the destination array could hold, change this

   ```
   scanf("%s", nama[i]);
   ```

   to be

   ```
   scanf("%99s", nama[i]);
   ```

   This change tells the program to not scan in more then 99 `char`s from the user.

   Why the `99` and not the `100`?

   ***Note*** that C-"string"s need one extra `char` to mark the end-of-the-string by placing a `'\0'` value (aka `NUL`), that is the so called `0`-terminator, or null-terminator (not to be mixed up with `NULL`, which is the null-pointer constant and not related to "string"s.).
2. Your `for`-loops loop `n` times. The arrays do not hold more then `SIZE` values.

   The code needs to make sure the loops do not loop more of then `SIZE` times.

   To ensure this add some so called "input validation" on `n` by doing for example:

   ```
   scanf("%d", &n);

   if (SIZE < n)
   {
     printf("Maximum number (%s) of allowed input records exceeded (%d).\n", SIZE, n);
     printf("Using %d instead of %d.\n", SIZE, n);
     n = SIZE;
   }
   ```

---

A word on defining arrays of "string"s:

Instead of doing:

```
char nama[SIZE][NAMALEN_MAX];
```

One *could* do:

```
typedef char[NAMALEN_MAX] Nama_Element;

Nama_Element nama[SIZE];
```

This would hide the fact that `nama` *still is* a 2D-array of `char`.

However *do not do this*, as it *unnecessarily obfuscates* your code.

Comment: That solved my problem. I still need a lot of study on C programming. Actually multi dimesional array haven't been told in my class, and my program should limit the input by SIZE because some class has maximum of 30 students. So I let n <=  SIZE

Comment: @SaifulRamadan: Please see my foot note on arrays of "string"s.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help

Comment: Nit: A *string* is a sequence of character values terminated by a 0-valued character code.  Strings are *stored* as arrays, but not every array contains a string.

Comment: @JohnBode: I mention this in detail later down in the answer. But you are right, as it stood is was incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your printf call is that `%s` expect a `char *`, and you give a `char`.

Your variable called `nama` is an array of `char`, so `nama[i]` is of type `char`, not `char *`. And the compiler must cast it automatically into an `int`. I think you want to use :

```
printf("%d\t  %s\t\t   %d\n", NIS[i], nama, nilai[i]);
```

And that's the same problem with your scanf call :

```
scanf("%s", nama);
```

Comment: Now if I input 2 data of nama [ i ] as Sai and Opi, I got output SOpi for every output of the nama data

Comment: I edited my answer, your scanf call should be modified as well. Does it help ?

Comment: Let me try, wait a sec @Olivier

Comment: D:\Works\ABKC1406\Hasil_Tes_Formatif\main.c|26|warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[30]' [-Wformat]|

Comment: Yes my bad, you don't need `&nama`, only `nama` in parameter of scanf. I edited my answer. You shouldn't warnings anymore.

Comment: I tried that. The output only show the last string that I input using scanf when I use : scanf("%s", nama);

Comment: Yes because `nama` is an array of `char`, not an array of `char *`. So `nama` cannot contain more than one name ! So each time, the name is replaced by the newest one, and you print the last name you entered, because you cannot store more than one name with a `char[]`. You should create an array of `char[]` to be able to store several names