# why segmentation fault in string but not char?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I simply want to print the first character of my string, as a string(%s format specifier) , it leads to segmentation fault. but when i am using %c format specifier it works fine. why is it happening ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char *str = "Feasible" ;
    printf("%s",*str);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any perfect reason for segmentation fault to occur ? and where is segmentation fault in my code ?

Comment: put `str` instead of `*str` inside `printf("%s",*str);`

Comment: `printf("%s",*str);` -> `printf("%s",str);`. And turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: The difference is that `%c` wants the *actual character* to be passed, not its location, hence the indirection `*str`.

Comment: Why do you want to print a single character as a string?

Comment: @RajeevSingh ,  str will print the complete string , not a single charater.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strings and character with printf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019615/strings-and-character-with-printf)

Comment: @chtz , i was just going through this code and i found this error , i am curious to know the reason and nothing .

Comment: @Matec009 yes, I just pointed out,  how to remove the segmentation fault!

Answer (score 2):

The segmentation fault occurs because your string is a char *, a pointer to a char. When you now pass *str in

```
printf ("%s\n", *str);
```

you pass the char value to which str points (the first char in the string) to printf. Printf expects to get a pointer to the first char of the string and tries to acces the given memory location, which then results in a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

For format specifier `"%s"`, `printf` expects a pointer to an array of characters; in other words, the value provided is interpreted as a memory address.
Note now that expression `*str` is dereferencing pointer `str` such that the result is a character value, i.e. `71` as the ASCII representation of `'F'`.
So if you use format specifier `"%s"` but provide value `71` as parameter, then `71` will be interpreted as memory address; and this memory address is very likely out of the allowed space to address, hence the segfault.

Format `"%c"`, in contrast, works, because it is expecting a character value like `71` (or `'F'`).

Answer (score 0):

`%s` is for printing string (via pointer to the first char).

`%c` is for printing a single char (via its ASCII value).

If you use `*str` is denotes the value of the first character pointed by `str`, so it needs `%c`.